# php blank page on file handling?

Tags: php, file, file-read

I am using this code copied from w3cschools. It works on loaclhost xampp but not working on live server. I am getting  blank page on live server.
PHP code is

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("products.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("products.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Blank page usually means syntax errors. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Does `products.txt` exist in the same folder as this script file? Does the file have the correct permissions to be read by the httpd account that apache is running under? I am assuming the LIVE server is unix

Comment: Check the error logs and ensure errors are being logged and/or displayed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Use file_exists http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php in a conditional statement and make sure it can be read. Check your paths also. Too many things can go wrong here.

Comment: Is the `products.txt` empty?

Comment: Please use absolute paths to filenames. imo Stuff like `products.txt` lives in a `data` directory. This will have a 'defined constant' such as `APP_DATA_DIR` that any part of the code can use and will always return the correct directory. Obviously, it is set differently when 'testing' but still the code doesn't change. Or you access it via a `class`, repository, proxy etc.

Comment: Yes file exist and working fine on local host xamp but when I shifted it to live server it is showing blank page without any error...

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by adding the code on the top of page
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);
Anyone can explain it? That why it got worked.